# Vertex of degree $3$ in simple graph with at least 6 vertices, or its complement.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph of at least 6 vertices and $G^c$ its complement. Show that either $G$ or $G^c$ has at least one vertex of degree at least 3.

My attempt: Let $n$ be the number of vertices, $E(G)$ the set of edges of $G$ and $V(G)$ the vertex set of $G$. By definition of graph complement, we know that $$|E(G)|+|E(G^c)|= \binom{n}{2} = \frac {n(n-1)}{2} \iff 2|E(G)|+2|E(G^c)|=n(n-1)$$ since $G$ is simple.

Then, by the handshaking lemma, $$n(n-1)=2\sum\limits_{v\in V(G)}deg(v) +2\sum\limits_{v\in V(G^c)}deg(v).$$ If every vertex of $G$ and $G^c$ has degree at most $2$, we have $n(n-1)\leq 2n+2n \implies n^2-5n \leq 0 \implies n\in [0,5]$, which is a contradiction since we assumed $n \geq 6$. So it's impossible that the degree of every vertex of G and G^c is at most $2.$

Is this correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It works, but we have a much stronger result: **Every** vertex $v$ is of degree $\ge 3$ in at least one of $G$, $G^c$. This is imply because among the at least five other vertices there must be $\ge 3$ with an edge or $\ge 3$ without an edge to $v$ in $G$.